# Add multiple language store code in the url ? example:www.domain.com/fr , www.domain.com/en

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I followed couple of answers on this and tried with creating a sub-directory for each store and copying two files index.php and .htacess from the root to the individual sub-directory. Then edit index.php file as:

```
$mageFilename = '/app/Mage.php';  to
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';

$mageFilename = '/app/Mage.php';        to
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';

require MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/bootstrap.php';  to
require MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

Mage::run('french_de', 'store');
```

Though i can access each store with with the URL as "domain.com/fr/" and "domain.com/en/", now when i click on any navigation menu, i get directed to the navigation menu of the default store.

I hope you would take you time to help me solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to edit the store base url for each store view.
Go to system->configuration->web. Select the `fr` store view from the top left selector and under the `Unsecure url` fill in this for the base url `http://www.domain.com/fr/`.
Do the same for the `Secure urls` if you have them enabled (and use `https`).
Do the same things for the `en` store view.

Comment: hello, thank you for the quick response. Doing so, the path for the skin, js ,  and media is lost. Hence i get only the plain HTML output.

Comment: you should change the skin, js and media url to `http://www.domain.com/js|skin|media/`